Sequelize : include association in create()
I'm working on a NodeJs + Sequelize + TypeScript app. I use sequelize-typescript lib if this matters.
I have those models :
@Table({
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true,
})
class Ingredient
  extends Model
{
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column
  public id!: number;
  @Column
  public name!: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => Department)
  @Column
  public departmentId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => Department)
  department: Department;

}

export default Ingredient;

@Table({
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true,
})
class Department
  extends Model<DepartmentAttributes, DepartmentInput>
{

  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column
  public id!: number;
  @Column
  public name!: string;

}

export default Department;

When I create a new Ingredient I would like that method returns the created Ingredient, with Department included.
I tried :
const ing = await Ingredient.create(payload, {
    include: [Department]
  });

But it doesn't work, I don't get the Department included in ing.
I also need it to be included in findAll, and this is working :
return await Ingredient.findAll({
    where: {
      ...(filters?.isDeleted && { deletedAt: { [Op.not]: null } }),
    },
    ...((filters?.isDeleted || filters?.includeDeleted) && { paranoid: true }),
    include: [Department],
  });

Any idea about why include doesn't work with create() method ?

Please show what's in payload

Hi, payload is : { name: 'test', departmentId: 3 }

Seems like you need to indicate include in the call await ing.reload({ include: [Department] }) instead of in create
